# customized download version is not working in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap 2.3 documentation if I customize the components and download I am getting the bootstrap.zip file which contains js and css files. But in bootstrap3 documentation if I do the same some unknown file with unknown file type is getting downloaded. Please suggest me how to get the corresponding js and css files in Bootstrap3 so that I can use them . Is it the error during upgradation?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Works for me when I go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. I get a zip file with js and css, both minified and unminified versions.

Comment: I am getting error like **Ruh roh! Could not save gist file, configuration not saved** and a file of unknown type is getting downloaded for the link [link](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: Maybe try a different browser. Also check that you have access to https://api.github.com/gists as this is used in the customizer code.

Comment: @mccannf : Thanks for your reply. I have tried in another system which is having no network restrictions.The proper js and css files are getting downloaded